# How Did They Do That?? Vol. 5: The "Singing Sword"

Tags: sound-design, singing-sword

You've heard the sound a million times in a thousand different contexts, but how did the original folks actually create it?

My link is to an oldie but goodie, and anyone who grew up in the 70s will be in for a treat. For those in the younger generation, listen for the sound of bionic "running" around 0:27.

[link text](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QWccQa7fI0g&feature=related)

Comment: Those may be the most epic body falls ever.

Comment: Just to be clear, we're *not* talking about this singing sword, right? http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6u8wBfDtZkE

Comment: That sound was like a must-use for all 80's shows, particularly cartoons!


Comment: p.s. Glad to see the series living on!

Comment: i love how they just slam the sfx through an echoplex and start jacking the feedback and moving the repro head around to creat that effect.

Comment: May be cheating a bit, but theres some interesting thoughts and ideas over at Gearslutz about it from a while back ;) http://www.gearslutz.com/board/post-production-forum/64510-sound-design-six-million-dollar-man-bionic-sound.html

Answer (score 2):

It was the tone wheel leakage from a B3. When run though a Leslie w/ the horn spinning it added a metalic phasing signature to it. The strait leakage is more usable vs the Leslie, which is more distant but added it's thing. Then into the funky Tel-Ray style echo/delay with feedback, which also had an adjustable square - sine wave LFO modulation on it like the PCM42's do, and you have the sound. [here is an embedded pdf file with the source sound see the attachment after downloading the pdf file](http://www.scribd.com/doc/126370354/Bionic)

Answer (score 1):

Im glad I read this as I was very familiar with the sound but didnt know what it was called. Just out of curiosity why is this sound called the singing sword?

Comment: That's what it's called in the Hanna-Barbera library, which I believe is the original source.

Answer (score 0):

To my ears it really really sounds like a feedback look, like they got to sound emitting objects real close together that also recorded. Like what you can do with two phones on a call with each other. What they used exactly? I don't know, but there's a whole expo (shame I can't find a link) of feedback sound creators. Look at what they did and you might find a cheap solution to your problem.

www.youtube.com/user/DIYFoley